# Are splices made with insulated cable connectors required to be inside a junction box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box, splicing, junction

I have a need to splice a 6/3 romex and 4/3 romex in my attic.  It would look something like this:

```
4/3  |-- (6/3) new destination
-----|
     |-- (4/3) original destination
```

I am looking at purchasing the following connector: 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UKGG0C6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UKGG0C6)

The current breaker is 70amp.  I will downgrade that to 50amp because of the 6/3 wire.

I have read conflicting reports on whether these connectors require a junction box or not.  Can someone please give guidance?  Please cite any references rather than just opinions!

Comment: What size breaker do you have feeding that original 4/3 cable?

Comment: It was 70amp.  It's my intention to go down to a 50amp breaker because of the 6/3 cable.

Comment: You do understand you'd need four of those, yes?  That thing is not 3 poles x 3 ports, it is 1 pole x3 ports and can only accommodate 3 wires period.  The wires can enter either from left or right but not both at once.  The top "port-like-thing" is actually where you put the allen wrench to torque it.   Go to the local electrical supply and ask for those with maximum size is #4.  It will fit your wires better and be cheaper also.  I paid $11 last time I needed a 3-wire #2.

Comment: Yep.  I understand that I'd need 4 of them.  Anyone know if I require a junction box?

Comment: From "Amazon Customer" so not necessarily a reliable source - in the Amazon Q & A:  *Do these connectors need to be enclosed inside a junction box? For household usage, yes. And if behind walls, without a doubt yes.*

Comment: Might be good to specify the country you are in given this seems to relate to regulatory requirements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You'll need a box, and a pretty chunky one at that

Splicing wire this large is indeed done with insulated mechanical splice connectors like the one you linked -- you will need one per wire, and a torque screwdriver or wrench, marked and calibrated in inch-pounds, to install them properly.  As to containing the splices, you will need something larger than a normal junction box -- in fact, what you need is called a *pull box*, and needs to be sized according to NEC 314.28(A):

> **(A) Minimum Size.** For raceways containing conductors
>   of 4 AWG or larger that are required to be insulated, and for
>   cables containing conductors of 4 AWG or larger, the minimum dimensions of pull or junction boxes installed in a
>   raceway or cable run shall comply with (A)(1) through
>   (A)(3). Where an enclosure dimension is to be calculated
>   based on the diameter of entering raceways, the diameter
>   shall be the metric designator (trade size) expressed in the
>   units of measurement employed.
>
> **(1) Straight Pulls.** In straight pulls, the length of the box
>   or conduit body shall not be less than eight times the metric
>   designator (trade size) of the largest raceway.
>
> **(2) Angle or U Pulls, or Splices.** Where splices or where
>   angle or U pulls are made, the distance between each raceway entry inside the box or conduit body and the opposite
>   wall of the box or conduit body shall not be less than six
>   times the metric designator (trade size) of the largest raceway
>   in a row. This distance shall be increased for additional entries
>   by the amount of the sum of the diameters of all other raceway
>   entries in the same row on the same wall of the box. Each row
>   shall be calculated individually, and the single row that provides the maximum distance shall be used.
>
> *Exception: Where a raceway or cable entry is in the wall
>   of a box or conduit body opposite a removable cover the
>   distance from that wall to the cover shall be permitted to
>   comply with the distance required for one wire per terminal
>   in Table 312.6(A).*
>
> The distance between raceway entries enclosing the
>   same conductor shall not be less than six times the metric
>   designator (trade size) of the larger raceway.
>
> When transposing cable size into raceway size in
>   314.28(A)(1) and (A)(2), the minimum metric designator
>   (trade size) raceway required for the number and size of
>   conductors in the cable shall be used.

Given that you are splicing in this box, and that a 4/3 W/G cable is equivalent to 4 4AWG THHNs (actually a bit less due to the ground being bare, but lets ignore that for now) or 212mm2 of fill, which *barely* fits down most types of 1" conduit, we wind up needing at least a 6" square box, and likely something more like an 8" square box.  Fortunately, a NEMA 1 pull box of that size (such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00529XCCM)) isn't too hard to get one's paws on -- your local electrical supply house should *definitely* be able to get one in for you.

Grounding the pull box, by the way, will require you to use either:

- a four-way insulated mechanical splice for the ground wires as well as an 8AWG copper pigtail from the insulated splice to the green ground screw in the box.
- or a ground bar in the pull box, attached to the box where the green ground screw goes, with the ground wires landed on that.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  For clarification, how would I go about grounding this setup?  I assume I can't just use one of these 3 way connectors and not ground the metal pull box?

Comment: @BryanFrederick -- edited in details on grounding

Comment: Something else to think about... at what point does it become easier to replace the entire run of wire, instead of trying to splice?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it must be in a junction box. There are splice connectors available for installation in a space where a junction box is not possible, but those splice connectors are explicitly rated for such a purpose; the connector you have proposed is not.

Putting a junction box in an attic is not that big of a deal. Just do that.

Comment: How large / what type of junction box would be appropriate?  I read that there are size limitations for any junction box with wire 4/3 and larger?

Comment: An ordinary junction box won't do here...4AWG puts you into pull box territory.

Comment: Good point. I missed how big that wire is.